# Can we script database testing using Selenium?

Tags: java, sql, selenium

If it required to write a script for minimal usage of SQL for database testing of a website using selenium or manual testing is enough?

Comment: Do you know the difference between an integration test and a unit test? Regardless, in my opinion, Selenium would be a poor choice to test a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Not selenium (a browser tester), but you could use [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/).

You should be using JBehave (or similar [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) tool) to drive your system testing.

You *could* do it via unit tests, but I wouldn't because it requires a database to be present and that's typically outside the scope of a "unit test". No point in using a mocking framework either, because it;s the database you want to test, not the code calling it.

Answer (score 0):

We use TSQLT. It a unit test framework but I use it as an e2e test automation tool. You can fake tables in Stg, ETL and target. Then you can write scripts that perform inserts, updates, deletes etc., run stored procedures and then compare expected vs actually results. Work pretty well and easy to use